# How to arrange the fields in notepad which is coming from db_send_email

Tags: sql-server, sendmessage

I have the notepad with the expected results...But the fields are not arranged properly.One column is coming in one line and another in another like.Its not looking good.I heard like we can set the column width for the result set.Please help me with the syntax and an example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean `sp_send_dbmail` procedure to send database mail but not `db_send_email`. In such case you can control your output format in the following way.

#### 1. Set width of output line to fixed value.

```sql
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name = 'Mailer',
  @recipients = 'undisclosed',
  @query = 'SELECT field_int
                 , field_varchar_50
                 , field_varchar_250
            FROM mytable' ,
  @query_result_no_padding = 0,
  @query_result_width = 400 ;
```

Selected width should be greater than sum of lengthes of all fields in the query, e.g. `@query_result_width = 400`. However, this will produce too wide lines especially in case `varchar(50)` or `varchar(250)` fields have many padding spaces.

#### 2. Truncate fields.

```sql
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name = 'Mailer',
  @recipients = 'undisclosed',
  @query = 'SELECT field_int
                 , LEFT(field_varchar_50, 25)
                 , LEFT(field_varchar_250, 25)
            FROM mytable' ,
  @query_result_no_padding = 0 ;
```

This will produce output where `varchar(50)` or `varchar(250)` will be truncated to 25 symbols. Of course, you can use any appropriate different value.

#### 3. Adjust field lengths.

Just add field lengths calculation and produce output with exact width.

```sql
DECLARE @iField_varchar_250_length
SELECT @iField_varchar_250_length = MAX(LEN(field_varchar_250)) FROM mytable

DECLARE @sQuery VARCHAR(200)
SELECT @sQuery = 'SELECT field_int
                       , LEFT(field_varchar_50, 25)
                       , LEFT(field_varchar_250, ' + CAST(@iField_varchar_250_length AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')
                  FROM mytable' ,

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name = 'Mailer',
  @recipients = 'undisclosed',
  @query = @sQuery,
  @query_result_no_padding = 0 ;
```